# update api fields in certificate

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-apiserver

I updated my cert manager to version 1.5 and my certificate automatically received a new api v1 field (as I understood it, cert manager did it himself using managed fields). Certificate are sealed using helm 3.

My certificates looked like this

apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1beta1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
name: name
spec:
dnsNames:
- dns.dns
secretName: testzzz
issuerRef:
name: neme
kind: ClusterIssuer

After updating version 1.5 , it began to look like this:

API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1
Kind:         Certificate
Metadata:
Creation Timestamp:  2023-05-23T15:20:16Z
Generation:          1
Managed Fields:
API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1beta1
Fields Type:  FieldsV1
fieldsV1:
f:spec:
.:
f:dnsNames:
f:issuerRef:
.:
f:kind:
f:name:
f:secretName:
Manager:      Go-http-client
Operation:    Update
Time:         2023-05-23T15:20:16Z
API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1
Fields Type:  FieldsV1
fieldsV1:
f:status:
f:conditions:
f:notAfter:
f:notBefore:
f:renewalTime:
Manager:      controller
Operation:    Update
Time:         2023-05-23T15:20:16Z
API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1
Fields Type:  FieldsV1
fieldsV1:
f:metadata:
f:annotations:
Manager:      kubectl-client-side-apply
Operation:    Update
Time:         2023-05-23T15:22:37Z
API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1beta1
Fields Type:  FieldsV1
fieldsV1:
f:metadata:
f:annotations:

Now in my helm templates I am trying to replace the api field cert-manager.io/v1beta1 -> cert-manager.io/v1 but when upgrading helm gives:

Error: UPGRADE FAILED: rendered manifests contain a new resource that already exists. Unable to continue with update: existing resource conflict: namespace: default, name: testzzz, existing_kind: cert-manager.io/v1, Kind=Certificate, new_kind: cert-manager.io/v1, Kind=Certificate

What can I do besides deleting Certificate and a new helm deployment? I would like to manually update these fields somehow, so that at the next "helm upgrade", helm accepts the new api v1 field.

I want to get an updated field in the help release without deleting the certificate or manually recreating it using a script or tool. I don 'T want to update certificate by deleting certificate and deploy it again using helm .

Comment: I think I've figured out the reason. The chart secret metadata contains a field with an old version of the api

secret sh.helm.release.v1.NAMECHART.v1 -> field data: release: DATA -> decode ->

"templates": [
  {
    "name": "templates/certificate.yaml",
    "data": " DATA_BASE64"
  }
],

decode ->

apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1beta1
kind: Certificate

Question is it possible to change this metadata field?